# Button not updating variable in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-3.8

Been working on a pesronal app and one of my TopLevel windows won´t work correctly. I need for the variable idd to be whatever the user inputs in the Entry widget, but something is wrong and I've tried everything I know of tkinter without results.

The widget I generate is the following:

```
def win_erase_id(parent):
    idd=-1
    wind=Toplevel(parent)
    wind.title("Enter id")
    lbl=Label(win,text="Enter player ID you want to erase:")
    svar=StringVar()
    ent=Entry(win,textvariable=svar)
    fr=Frame(win)

    def butA_m():
        idd=int(svar.get())
        wind.destroy()

    def butC_m():
        idd=-1
        wind.destroy()

    butA=Button(fr,text="Accept",command=butA_m,relief=RAISED)
    butC=Button(fr,text="Cancel",command=butC_m,relief=RAISED)
    lbl.grid(row=0,sticky="nswe")
    ent.grid(row=1,sticky="nswe")
    fr.grid(row=2,sticky="nswe")

    butA.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
    butC.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=BOTH)
   
    wind.wait_window()
    return idd
```

I thought that by setting a textvariable and then in the method butA_m asking that variable for its value the end variable would be the integer I needed, but the value I get is always -1. Tried using .delete() and .insert()  on the Entry widget but wouldn't work either.

**Edit:** I accidentally erased some "d"s from the `wind` instances but already corrected it.

Comment: You need to declare `idd` as `nonlocal` inside `butA_m()` and `butC_m()` functions, otherwise it is a local variable inside those functions.

Comment: Added the `nonlocal` keyword before `idd` in both methods but now vscode's pylint marks the `int(...)` as _invalid sintax_ error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nonlocal**, as stated by somebody before me actually solves it, I just did not understand how to use it, but after checking [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_nonlocal.asp) I ended up correcting my code and it worked.

```
    def butA_m():
        nonlocal idd
        idd=int(svar.get())
        wind.destroy()
    
    def butC_m():
        nonlocal idd
        idd=-1
        wind.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your top level window is called `wind` for the first two lines, but after that you've referenced to an unbound window `win`. Try changing this to start, see if you are still getting the same problem

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, they are all called as wind, maybe erased the d when formating the question.